# Inequality square root between two positive commutative operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given two **commutative positive operators** $X, Y \geq 0$, how can you show that $X \leq Y \Leftrightarrow \sqrt X \leq \sqrt Y$ ?

$X \leq Y$ means that $Y-X$ is a positive operator.

I did the $\Leftarrow$ using the commutativity and $Y-X=(\sqrt Y + \sqrt X)(\sqrt Y - \sqrt X)$ but I can't manage to do the $\Rightarrow$.

Note that **I can't use spectral theory**, at least not in infinite dimension, since we didn't learn it yet.